# Error while running a program on java on visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

This is the porgram which I am running on visual studio code

[image]

When I run the program I am getting this error box
[image]

After getting the error box, it is showing this page.
[image]

What shall be done in this for the program to run on VS Code?

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not supply code, error messages, or other textual output as images.  Instead, include the text directly in your question, properly formatted.

Comment: Those errors are from different code to what you posted

Comment: What is the contents of "exercise_prog1.java"?  Apparently, that file refers to an identifier named `exp` that has not been defined.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character and should be CamelCase not Snake_case

Comment: Yeah the error literally tells you what's wrong `exp` and `exerciseprog2` cannot be resolved to a variable so you need to show us the code that contains these two 'variables'

Comment: You might want to try moving the source file you show to a different directory.  It sounds like you've got a directory full of Java files, and you're attempting to execute one of them.  Java is likely attempting to compile all of the source files in that same directory, and some of them are not valid and so don't compile, and so you get the errors you're seeing.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? This [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) may be helpful. –

Answer (score 0):

There should be multiple java files inside the folder you are currently opening in vscode and you are running one of them. There is a bug in another java script that causes a compilation error when you run the current file.

It doesn't matter, you just need to click on `Proceed` in the popup, which will continue to run the current code. As long as your current code has no errors, the program will run successfully and output the result.

[image]

Another way is to install [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and then use the `Run Code` option it brings to run the code. This way it will only compile and run the current file, and will not bring compile errors.

[image]

*But be aware that **Code Runner** may have errors when your file structure is complex.*